# How to implemente an Offline GWT Map

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, gwt, offline

Can anyone help me to create an offline Map on GWT, i heard talking about OpenLayers but i didnt find any source code, do you have any idea about this.
Thank you.

Comment: googling openlayers brings you to their website, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will want the [GWT-Openlayers Wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/gwtopenlayers/gwt-openlayers/overview) for [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/). Be warned it is a 0. Version, so it is not perfect, but it does work.

Edit:

You will also want an offline map, I used this one. Its not perfect but the best free one I know.
[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

It's been over a year I done this and I don't have access to the source but I remember that this helped me. No need for SmartGWT its the same principle with pure GWT:
[SmartGWT wrapper for OpenLayers](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4368&highlight=openlayers). Actually it should be easier with pure GWT.

Comment: Tahnk you so mutch, i followed the documentation with the maven GWT-https://bitbucket.org/gwtopenlayers/gwt-openlayers/overview , but i found that they use an online map !

Comment: If with offline you mean Client only. Then rethink, you don't want Mozilla to run a 1GB file thats not going to work (and defeats the point of using GWT). The map needs to be on your server.